# How to create a rule to identify all the files with a .c extension on the included directories as a pre-requisite for a makefile rule?

Tags: makefile

If I have the rule, where OBJECTS_C is a list of object files with NO path:

```
$(OBJECTS_C): %.o:  %.c
     do stuff
```

how can I specify that the %.c file is supposed to match the same file stem, but the path can be anything?

Like suppose I have source/file1.c and source/dir1/file2.c 
I want to modify the rule such that file1.o and file2.o are created on the current directory, regardless of where the source files are on the included directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use VPATH (as a variable or using the `vpath` directive) to add all the relevant directories to the list of directories searched for prerequisites.

(VPATH is for all prerequisites, vpath only for those matching the pattern it is given)

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search) is the relevant documentation.

That said, beware of name conflicts : if you have src files that have the same name but are in different directories, you might experiment troubles. A better way would be to have your build tree reflects your source tree.